# Small calculator

Tags: ios, swift

I have code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var summaryLbl: UILabel!
var actualNumber: Double = 0
var previousNumber: Double = 0
var operationMath: Bool = false
var operation = 0


@IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if operationMath == true
    {
        summaryLbl.text = String(sender.tag)
        actualNumber = Double(summaryLbl.text!)!
        operationMath = false
    }
    else
    {
        if summaryLbl.text == "0" {
            summaryLbl.text = ""
        }
        summaryLbl.text = summaryLbl.text! + String(sender.tag)
        actualNumber = Double(summaryLbl.text!)!
    }
}

@IBAction func buttons(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if summaryLbl.text != "" && sender.tag != 10 && sender.tag != 17
    {
        previousNumber = Double(summaryLbl.text!)!

        if sender.tag == 13
        {
            summaryLbl.text = "/";
        }
        else if sender.tag == 14
        {
            summaryLbl.text = "x";
        }
        else if sender.tag == 15
        {
            summaryLbl.text = "-";
        }
        else if sender.tag == 16
        {
            summaryLbl.text = "+";
        }

        operation = sender.tag
        operationMath = true;
    }
    else if sender.tag == 17
    {
        if operation == 13
        {
            let summary = rounding(number: previousNumber / actualNumber)
            summaryLbl.text = summary
        }
        else if operation == 14
        {
            let summary = rounding(number: previousNumber * actualNumber)
            summaryLbl.text = summary
        }
        else if operation == 15
        {
            let summary = rounding(number: previousNumber - actualNumber)
            summaryLbl.text = summary
        }
        else if operation == 16
        {
            let summary = rounding(number: previousNumber + actualNumber)
            summaryLbl.text = summary
        }
        else if operation == 11 //TODO: negative numbers
        {
            let summary = rounding(number: previousNumber + actualNumber)
            summaryLbl.text = summary
        }
        else if operation == 12 //TODO: percentages
        {
            let summary = rounding(number: (previousNumber * actualNumber) / 100)
            summaryLbl.text = summary
        }
    }
    else if sender.tag == 10
    {
        summaryLbl.text = "0"
        previousNumber = 0;
        actualNumber = 0;
        operation = 0;
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    summaryLbl.text = "0"
    previousNumber = 0;
    actualNumber = 0;
    operation = 0;
}

func rounding (number: Double) -> String {
    let numberAfterRounding = String(number)
    return numberAfterRounding
}
```

I'm doing a small calculator.

I have a problem with:

1. I always get a result eg 5.0, 25.0, 18.0 (with the tip: .0) - how to get rid of it?
2. How to make addition / negative numbers? After pressing the button operation == 11 I would like the number to become negative, or if it's negative then it's positive (just like doing an Apple calculator in the iPhone)
3. Percentages do not really work for me :(

Comment: Problem 2: number * -1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer for Problem 1:**
Suppose you have result of 3.0 and you want to display just `"3"` instead of `"3.0"`, and for `1.23`, you want to display `"1.23"` . First round the number, check if the rounded number and result is the same. If they are the same, convert it to Int and interpolate it.
Here is the code.

```
let result: Double = 3.0
let rounded = result.rounded()
if (result == rounded) { yourLabel.text = "\(Int(result))" }
else { yourLabel.text = "\(result)" }
```

**Answer for Problem 2:**
Swift has `negate()` function which does exactly what you are looking for.

```
var result: Double = 30
result.negate() // it's now -30
result.negate() // it's now 30 again
```

**Answer for Problem 3:**
I assume when you say percentage(%), you means modulus .
In swift, you can't use %(modulus operator) on floating points like `3.0 % 1.0`. Instead, you must use `truncatingRemainder(dividiedBy:)` function.

```
result.truncatingRemainder(dividedBy: 10) // can be any number you like
```